# The Probability of $k$ events in $n$ systems within some time period

Tags: probability

Imagine I sit down at a giant array of $n$ lights. When engaged, each light will pulse with an average of $s$ seconds between pulses. Each pulse lasts for some constant $t_{\Delta}$ seconds. A light can turn on and off again multiple times, but it cannot be turned on again when it is already turned on. I will hit a button at $t=0$ to engage the system and observe it for $t_{*}$ seconds. What is the probability that there is some $t\in[0,t_{*}]$ that I will observe $k$ lights turned on simultaneously?

---

**What follows is my own poor attempts at modeling this myself...**

Each light seems to be the exponential distribution $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ with $\lambda=1/s$.
The particular lights that are on do not matter -- I only care that $k$ of them happen.
For the purposes of simplification, I assume $t_{\Delta}$ is significantly less than $t_*$ so we the times when $t_1 \pm t_{\Delta}$ is not in $[0, t_*]$ are mostly irrelevant.
I chose the joint probability of $n$ lights, $k$ of them on and $n-k$ of them off, multiplied by the number of ways to arrange my $n$ lights into $k$:

$$
  P\binom{n\ \text{systems}}{k\ \text{events}} =
    \binom{n}{k}
    \int_{0}^{t_*}
    \int\cdots\int_{t_1-t_{\Delta}}^{t_1+t_{\Delta}}
    \left[
      \left(\prod_{i=1}^{k}\lambda e^{-\lambda t_i}\right)
      \left(\prod_{i=k+1}^{n}1-\lambda e^{-\lambda t_i}\right)
    \right]
    dt_n\ldots dt_1
$$

As an example expansion (since I'm not sure if my $\int \cdots \int$ thing makes any sense) with $4$ systems and $2$ concurrent events:

$$
  P(4,2) =
    \binom{4}{2}
    \int_{0}^{t_*}
    \int_{t_1-t_{\Delta}}^{t_1+t_{\Delta}}
    \int_{t_1-t_{\Delta}}^{t_1+t_{\Delta}}
    \int_{t_1-t_{\Delta}}^{t_1+t_{\Delta}}
      \lambda e^{-\lambda t_1}
      \lambda e^{-\lambda t_2}
      (1-\lambda e^{-\lambda t_3})
      (1-\lambda e^{-\lambda t_4})
    dt_4 dt_3 dt_2 dt_1
$$

While this process seems correct, it seems quite computationally intensive (especially since my $n$ values are usually over $1000$). Another issue I have is most approximations do not work for me, since my $\lambda$ value is usually less than $10^{-6}$.

As a slight simplification, I can replace all $t_i$s where $i>1$ with $t_+$. However, this does not solve the fundemental issue of having to perform an $n$-integral to reach my answer.

$$
  P\binom{n\ \text{systems}}{k\ \text{events}} =
    \binom{n}{k}
    \int_{0}^{t_*}
    \int\cdots\int_{t-t_{\Delta}}^{t+t_{\Delta}}
      \left(\lambda e^{-\lambda t_1}\right)
      \left(\lambda e^{-\lambda t_+}\right)^{k-1}
      \left(1-\lambda e^{-\lambda t_+}\right)^{n-k}
    dt_+^{n-1}
    dt_1
$$

**So the question is:** Is there a way to calculate $P$ that is somewhat more tractable than performing an $n$-integral?

---

I have only had one semi-successful attempt to simplify the problem so far.
I tried to break the problem into components and then use simple binomial probability in the last step.

$$
  Q\binom{n\ \text{systems}}{k\ \text{events}} =
    \binom{n}{k}
    \left(P\binom{k}{k}\right)^{k}
    \left(1 - P\binom{k}{k}\right)^{n-k}
$$

While I thought $Q$ would simply be an inaccurate version of $P$, I discovered a surprising (to me) relationship between the two functions.

$$
  R\binom{n\ \text{systems}}{k\ \text{events}} =
    2^{n - k}
    P\binom{k}{k}
    Q\binom{n}{k} /
    Q\binom{k}{k}
$$

This $R$ function is quite accurrate for low values of $n$, but as $n$ grows, it becomes wildly inaccurrate. There are two problems I have with $R$. The first is that I only really care about large values of $n$, so the inaccuracy is detremental. The second is that I have no idea why it presents me such a sort of okay view of the world.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're assuming and what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure what more you are asking for. The only assumption is that my $n$ systems are properly modeled by $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$. What I'm looking for is the likelihood that, given $n$ systems, what is the likelihood that $k$ events will happen within some time period of each other.

Comment: But what do you mean by "properly modeled by"? And can more than one event occur within one system?

Comment: It might be easier to explain this way: I have $n$ lights that turn on with an average of $s$ seconds between turning on and they stay on for $t_{\Delta}$ before turning off (so exponential distribution with $\lambda=1/s$). A light cannot turn on again until it is turned off, but can turn on and off multiple times. What I would like to know is the likelihood that $k$ lights will be on at the same time in the window I care about ($t_{*}$).

Comment: All right, and are you assuming the systems are stationary (i.e., time-invariant), or on the other hand are you assuming an initial condition that all the lights begin in the off state?

Comment: All lights begin as off.

Comment: Here $t_\Delta$ is a given non-random constant? And the systems are independent of one another? And $t_*$ is an interval: $t_*=[t_a,t_b]$?

Comment: Oh, or more likely, you mean $t_*$ is a positive number, and you are looking at the interval $[0,t_*]$ and want to know the probability that there exists $t\in[0,t_*]$ such that $k$ lights are on at time $t$ (i.e., that $k$ lights are on simultaneously at some time before $t_*$)?

Comment: Yes -- $t_{\Delta}$ is basically constant (in reality, it is dependent on the number of lights that are on, but it varies so little it probably doesn't matter). And if I understand your second statement, then yes to that as well. I edited the question with a rephrasing of the problem at the start...hopefully it will be better than my first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method that would give you a nice, exact solution to the problem as currently formulated; it has the appearance of being intractable. But what you could do is run simulations, find the proportion of simulations for which the event occurs (that $k$ of $n$ lights are on at some point before $t_*$), and use this to construct a confidence interval for the probability.

The iterated integrals that you have written down do not correspond to the probability that you are looking for. The way to think of it is that there is a random subset $A \subseteq [0,t_*]$ representing the times when $k$ lights are on, and using an iterated integral similar to what you have written down, you could find the expected value of the measure of $A$ (i.e., the expected value of the sum of the lengths of the disjoint intervals which $A$ will consist of), at least in the case where we simplify the problem by assuming each light can only turn on one time. However, you are looking for the probability that $A$ is non-empty, which is not the same thing as the expected value of the measure of $A$.

If we modified the problem by assuming that the light stays on for a random, exponentially-distributed amount of time (instead of for a constant time $t_\Delta$), then the problem could be described by a continuous-time Markov chain (with $n+1$ states), and it would be more hopeful that an exact solution could be found. Alternatively, if you are interested in the original problem but are willing to settle for asymptotic results (as $n\to\infty$), then you could look at the stochastic process $X(t)$ giving the proportion of lights on at time $t$, approximate this as a Gaussian process, and work from there.